# ASP.NET Linq Accessing nested select element & binding to repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

**Repeater Bound in ASP.NET**
I want the nested select elements to be bound to a repeater. Here goes my code:

```
var ret = (from post in db.Posts.ToList()
    orderby post.PostedDate descending
    select new
    {
        Message = post.Message,
        PostedBy = post.PostedBy,
        PostedByName = post.UserProfile.UserName,
        PostedDate = post.PostedDate,
        PostId = post.PostId,
        PostComments = from comment in post.PostComments.ToList() 
            orderby comment.CommentedDate
            select new
            {
                CommentedBy = comment.CommentedBy,
                CommentedByName = comment.UserProfile.UserName,
                CommentedDate = comment.CommentedDate,
                CommentId = comment.CommentId,
                Message = comment.Message,
                PostId = comment.PostId
            }
        }).AsEnumerable();
```

On aspx page my post get bind `<%#Eval("PostedBy")%>` but I want out the comments at specific post and I am unable to bind comments elements like `commentedby`, `commentid`, `commentdate`.
`<%#Eval("CommentedBy")%>` but it doesn't get bound.

Please help me on this matter, how can I bind `CommentedDate` and other elements to comment box layout?

Comment: use repeater for PostComments and then use CommentedBy and so on

Comment: Put the html of repeater in your question.